# How can I block row and column insertion on Excel?

Tags: excel, vsto

Is there a way for me to not let my user insert rows/columns on my spreadsheet?

I have an Excel 2013 Workbook project and I have to block user access to insert/delete rows and columns.

Comment: If 2013 is roughly equivalent to 2010 you can protect the workbook structure in Review, Protect Workbook, click on structure.

Comment: @geoB, that only works for adding/deleteing sheets.  It does nothing to protect the rows/columns of individual worksheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You just Unlock all of the cells on the worksheet and then protect it.  Just uncheck all options except Insert Rows, Insert Columns, Delete Rows and Delete Columns.

Answer (score -1):

Set AllowNew and AllowDelete property to false to restrict user from creating new rows or delete a row from excel list object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.allownew(v=vs.110).aspx

```
DataSet.Tables["tablename"].DefaultView.AllowDelete = false;
BindingSource.AllowNew = false;
```